# Python - Round to nearest 9 (nearest unit, ten, hundred)

Tags: python, rounding

Can you think of a function in Python to round any number to the nearest 9?

The exception is that the rounding is to the nearest unit, ten, hundred, millennium, etc.

```
76 --> 69 
242 --> 239 
8434 --> 8399 
34857 --> 33999
987482 --> 986999
```

Comment: Yes I can, thank you.

Comment: Your example and your words do not line up, can you explain exactly what you mean?

Comment: Why does `987482` rounds to `986999` and not `987479`?

Comment: Round to the previous numerical unit. It is to determine prices that make commercial sense.

Comment: Perhaps you can give a more detailed specification of what qualifies as "commercial sense" for these purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function:

```
import math

def round_to_nearest_9(number):
    number_of_fixed_digits = 1
    factor = max(10, math.pow(10, math.floor(math.log10(number))
                     - number_of_fixed_digits))
    return (number // factor) * factor - 1
```

Note 1: if you change the `- 1` in the end to a `-0.01` you even get it rounded including the 99 cents
Note 2: Your desired behavior is dangerous for small amounts, as 19 -> 9

**Edit:**
 @MarkDickinson proposed following modification which deals with the undesirable behavior referenced in Note 2:

```
def round_to_nearest_9(number):
    number_of_fixed_digits = 1
    factor = max(10, math.pow(10, math.floor(math.log10(number))
                     - number_of_fixed_digits))
    return (number - 1 // factor) * factor - 1
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the small amounts. Eventually I would add a minimum amount to use the function. Thanks!

Comment: If you use `(number + 1) // factor * factor - 1` in the last line, that deals with odd cases like `19` rounding to `9` and makes the rounding idempotent.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you, this is a really good modification! I wont include it thogh, as it's not the behavior OP was looking for...

Comment: Can you give examples where that modification doesn't provide the behaviour the OP is looking for? I can't really believe that the OP wants 19 to "round" to 9.

Comment: @MarkDickinson OP provided the example 76 -> 69 which is the same as 19 -> 9, while you're modification would lead to 19 -> 19. Don't get me wrong here, I agree, that your modification leads to a generally more desirable behavior.